# Serial monitor sends encoded data instead of text

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I'am trying to read through serial port of my Nodemcu (esp8266) for some reasons am not getting text but encoded characters like ??c113b##. Any reasons for this issue? Am confused!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by baudrate conflict. You have to check the baudrate of your device first, and then you can also change the baudrate of your terminal application.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I had to change both baud rates to 9600 and it now works!

Comment: I am happy to hear it from you. :)